# Can’t resolve snapshot artifact with classifier in MavenLocal

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have an error, when trying to resolve next dependency

> debugApi group: 'com.keypr.kaos.common', name: 'commons', version: project.version, classifier: 'debug', ext: 'aar'
>
> ```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':commons-kaos:debugCompileClasspath'.
> > Could not find commons-debug.aar (com.keypr.kaos.common:commons:3.1.40-SNAPSHOT:20180912.132455-2).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/home/vandalko/.m2/repository/com/keypr/kaos/common/commons/3.1.40-SNAPSHOT/commons-3.1.40-20180912.132455-2-debug.aar
> ```

Repository:

> ```
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko 62360 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132454-1-debug.aar
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko    32 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132454-1-debug.aar.md5
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko    40 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132454-1-debug.aar.sha1
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko  1595 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132454-1.pom
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko    32 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132454-1.pom.md5
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko    40 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132454-1.pom.sha1
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko  1233 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132455-2.pom
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko    32 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132455-2.pom.md5
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko    40 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132455-2.pom.sha1
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko 56179 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132455-2-release.aar
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko    32 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132455-2-release.aar.md5
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko    40 вер 12 16:24 commons-3.1.40-20180912.132455-2-release.aar.sha1
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko  1035 вер 12 16:24 maven-metadata.xml
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko    32 вер 12 16:24 maven-metadata.xml.md5
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vandalko vandalko    40 вер 12 16:24 maven-metadata.xml.sha1
> ```

Metadata

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
>   <groupId>com.keypr.kaos.common</groupId>
>   <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
>   <version>3.1.40-SNAPSHOT</version>
>   <versioning>
>     <snapshot>
>       <timestamp>20180912.132455</timestamp>
>       <buildNumber>2</buildNumber>
>     </snapshot>
>     <lastUpdated>20180912132455</lastUpdated>
>     <snapshotVersions>
>       <snapshotVersion>
>         <extension>pom</extension>
>         <value>3.1.40-20180912.132455-2</value>
>         <updated>20180912132455</updated>
>       </snapshotVersion>
>       <snapshotVersion>
>         <classifier>release</classifier>
>         <extension>aar</extension>
>         <value>3.1.40-20180912.132455-2</value>
>         <updated>20180912132455</updated>
>       </snapshotVersion>
>       <snapshotVersion>
>         <classifier>debug</classifier>
>         <extension>aar</extension>
>         <value>3.1.40-20180912.132454-1</value>
>         <updated>20180912132454</updated>
>       </snapshotVersion>
>     </snapshotVersions>
>   </versioning>
> </metadata>
> ```

As you can see, maven-metadata.xml points to correct version but Gradle tries to load different one...

Same question on Gradle forum because I'm kinda desperate https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cant-resolve-snapshot-artifact-with-classifier-in-mavenlocal/28589

Comment: Please show your pom file ......